# Does omnet++ 5.0 supports 3D programming?

Tags: omnet++

Can I use 3D scenario for simulation in omnet++? 3D visualization feature added in 5.0 does permit assigning z-coordinate to node?

Comment: Show us what you have tried by posting some code or describe more where you have been facing some issue, otherwise this question will be closed soon.

Answer (score 3):

OMNeT++ does NOT deal with node coordinates at all. The simulation kernel does not know anything about the position of the nodes. Neither 2D nor 3D. It is your model itself that must keep track of the position and is up to you to decide how to do that. Since OMNeT++ 5.0 you can easily visualize your model in a 3D view using OpenSceneGraph, but still you have to keep track of your node positions in your own model.

Your best bet is to take a look at the samples/osg-* examples.